# create htmlhelper instance of another type

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, extension-methods, html-helper

I have *HtmlHelper* extension method which can accept one template parameter of type T. Next, inside method i want to return editors for some fields in the object marked with special attribute. The problem is that i call this method for instance of *HtmlHelper*<*TModel*>, but inside the method i need instance of *HtmlHelper*<*T*> to use its *Editor* method. I've tried to create the default instance like this:

```
var html = new HtmlHelper<T>(new ViewContext(), new ViewPage());
```

but, of course, it doesn't work.
So, how could i create correct instance?

Comment: "It doesn't work" does not tell us anything. Please explain the _actual_ results you get and tell us the result you expect. Also, please provide some more code to demonstrate what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to re-instance it.

did you try something like this:

```
public static IHtmlString MyExtensionMethod<T>(this HtmlHelper html, T model) where T : IMyModel
{
    //your logic that returns a new HtmlString with html.TextBox for example
}
```